Delete input value after format it into group of 4 digits in JavaScript
I have a card-number input which when type numbers in it, it will be formatted as a group of "4 digits" and a "whitespace" after it instead of writing the numbers as 16 digits without any whitespace
The code I use
input.value = input.value.replace(/\d{4}/g, "$& ");

Bug
After replacing the input.value in format that I want, I can not delete the value unless I click on a specific group of numbers, for example:
input.value is:
"1234 5678 9123 4567 "
Now when I press "Backspace key" on keyboard, it won't delete the numbers, to do so, I need click on "4567" to be able to delete this group.
How can I fix this?

That bug occurs because your regex have a small issue.
I recreated the input-text-replacing functionality with your line of code and mine.
Yours:
input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    let inputValue = input.value;

    inputValue = inputValue.replace(/(\d{4})/g, "$& "); // Adding spaces.
});

Mine:
input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    let inputValue = input.value;
    
    inputValue = inputValue.replace(/\D/g, ""); // Only numbers are allowed.
    inputValue = inputValue.replace(/(\d{4})(?=\d)/g, "$& "); // Adding spaces.
    
    input.value = inputValue.slice(0, 19); // Limiting to 16 numbers.
});

Hope this would work!

By adding trim() method, problem was solved
input.value = input.value.replace(/\d{4}/g, "$& ").trim();

